# Tokenización Rest Redsys

Tags: php, rest, curl

Estoy intentando implementar la tokenización con Redsys en mi aplicación con PHP. Para ello, estoy utilizando su entorno de prueba y los datos de las tarjetas y clave de comercio que te proporcionan. He probado a hacerlo de mil maneras distintas y no hay manera de que funcione, la petición curl me devuelve {"errorCode":"SIS0042"}", según la documentación este error es porque no se genera bien la firma.

A continuación os pongo el código que estoy utilizando, si me podéis ayudar os lo agradezco un montón, me estoy volviendo loca:

```
// Datos de la tarjeta proporcionados por Redsys para pruebas
                $numTarjeta = "4918019160034602"; 
                $fechaV = "3412"; 
                $cvv = "123"; 

                // Datos de la petición
                $datosPeticion = array(
                    "DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT" => "0",
                    "DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY" => "978",
                    "DS_MERCHANT_ORDER" => "0281WjRq",
                    "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE" => "999008881",
                    "DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL" => "1",
                    "DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE" => "0",
                    "DS_MERCHANT_PAN" => $numTarjeta,
                    "DS_MERCHANT_EXPIRYDATE" => $fechaV,
                    "DS_MERCHANT_CVV2" => $cvv,
                    "DS_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER" => "REQUIRED"
                );
                

                // Convertir los datos de la petición a JSON
                $jsonDatosPeticion = json_encode($datosPeticion);

                $datosBase64 = base64_encode($jsonDatosPeticion);
                
                // Clave secreta del comercio proporcionada por Redsys para el entorno de pruebas
                $claveComercio = "sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7";

                $clave_diversificada = base64_decode($claveComercio) . base64_encode($datosPeticion["DS_MERCHANT_ORDER"]);

                $firma = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $datosBase64, $clave_diversificada, true));


                // Preparar la petición cURL
                $ch = curl_init('https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/rest/trataPeticionREST');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
                    'Ds_SignatureVersion' => 'HMAC_SHA256_V1',
                    'Ds_MerchantParameters' => $datosBase64,
                    'Ds_Signature' => $firma
                )));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                // Enviar la petición
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Ya verificaste la generación de la clave según la documentación de redsys ?

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregando este parametro al `$datosPeticion`

```
'DS_MERCHANT_DIRECTPAYMENT'   => 'true'
```

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]